# How to find subset of numbers in array that equals to 10?

Tags: c#

I want to find the sum of all subsets of adjacent numbers.

So if the set is 6 1 2 2 5
I want to find (the sum of)

```
6 1 2 2 5
6 1 2 2 
1 2 2 5
6 1 2
1 2 2
2 2 5
6 1
1 2
2 2
2 5
```

So I want to find not anly subsets of 2 numbers,but more(example input: 6 1 2 2 5 -> 6+2+2=10 or 1+2+2+5=10) and print them.

```
   using System;
    class Subset
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] num = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int[] number = new int[num.Length];

            for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
            {
                number[a] = Convert.ToInt32(num[a]);
            }

            int sum;
            bool found = false;


            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                sum = 0;
                for (int j = i; j < 5; j++)
                {

                    sum = sum + number[j];
                    if (sum == 10)
                    {

                        found = true;

                        for (int k = i; k < j; k++)
                        {
                            Console.Write("{0} + ", number[k]);
                        }
                        Console.Write(number[j]);
                        Console.Write(" = 10\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            if (found == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no zero subset\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to the subset sum problem. The only way to really find a combination that adds up to ten (or even all combinations), you will have to test all combinations. I am not sure if you want combinations of any size, or only two numbers. The examples you give only involve examples where two numbers add up to ten, which can be easily done by checking for all pairs.

```
for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    for (int j = 0, j < i; j++)
        if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] == 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = 10", numbers[i], numbers[j];
            return;
        }

Console.WriteLine("no subset that sums up to 10");
```

If however you want to find any subset of numbers that add up to ten, you have to consider all subsets of the set you are given. The best way to do this is using dynamic programming. You loop through the array of numbers and for each number you make the decision to either include the element in the subset or not. Let's look at the following method:

```
bool SubsetSum(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int sum)
{
    if (startIndex == numbers.Length - 1) // base case, only one element to consider
        return numbers[startIndex] == sum || sum = 0;

    return SubsetSum(numbers, startIndex + 1, sum)                       // don't take the current element
        || SubsetSum(numbers, startIndex + 1, sum - numbers[startIndex]; // take the current element
}
```

This method first checks if we arrived at the last element. In that case, we have two easy cases to consider: the sum we want to reach is 0, so we don't take the element, or the sum we want to reach is equal to the last element, in which case we do take it. Otherwise, there is no valid solution.
In all the other cases, we just branch into two paths, either taking or not taking the element into the subset.

This algorithm will run in exponential time in the amount of numbers as input. You can speed this up by using memorisation. You can create a huge table and save for every pair of startIndex and sum the outcome value. That way you are sure you will never evaluate the same thing twice. (Look up dynamic programming to learn more about this)

The method I described above only returns if a subset exists. To actually find the subset, you will also have to pass back the indices of the elements you have added to the subset. I won't work that out, as it makes the thing a lot more complicated. If you use a table in the dynamic programming approach, you are also able to use some backtracking techniques to find the right indices in linear time.

Comment: If all the elements are non-negative, you can do it in O(kN), which is number of strictly positive elements in array multiplied by target.